# Multiple Custom Fonts for application without specific TargetType

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to import two custom fonts into my application. For now, I have added the fonts in respectively the `.Droid/Assets` and `.iOS/Resources` directories and for iOS loaded it in my Info.plist.

In my App.xaml I do the following to load the fonts in my PCL:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Name="BoldFont" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                        <OnPlatform.Android>PT_Sans-Narrow-Web-Regular.ttf#PT Sans Narrow</OnPlatform.Android>
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>PT Sans Narrow</OnPlatform.iOS>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

However, i wish to be able to use multiple fonts in my Labels, being the reason why i added the following code into my `<ResourceDictionary>`:

```
<Style x:Name="RegularFont" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <OnPlatform.Android>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#Roboto Condensed</OnPlatform.Android>
                <OnPlatform.iOS>Roboto Condensed</OnPlatform.iOS>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the error:

> A resource with the key 'Xamarin.Forms.Label' is already present in the ResourceDictionary

Furthermore, do I really have to make my TargetType specific to the Label, if say, I want to use the fonts globally regardless if it's a `Label` or an `Entry`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, with Style, use x:Key instead of x:Name.  That will avoid the error message you're seeing.

```
<Style x:Key="RegularFont" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily">
        <Setter.Value>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <OnPlatform.Android>RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf#Roboto Condensed</OnPlatform.Android>
                <OnPlatform.iOS>Roboto Condensed</OnPlatform.iOS>
            </OnPlatform>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sometimes you can share Style definitions between types. The best way to do that is to use a TargetType that is a common base class that defines the properties you want to set. Unfortunately, there is no such common base class between Label and Entry.  They each independently define FontFamily.